# Getting this exception: "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. Parameter name: key"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I have some objects called `Box`es that I'm trying to list in a table. To do this, I'm using Automapper to map them to my `BoxedElectrodesRowModel`. However, I'm having a lot of trouble due to each `Box` having another object nested within it, called `SerialNumber`.

Specifically, trying to map a list of `SerialNumberName`s from each `Box`'s `SerialNumber`s to the list of `SerialNumber` strings in my `BoxedElectrodesModel` seems to be causing a lot of issues.

**Here is the AutoMapper code:**

```
c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BoxId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BoxID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumbers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers.Select(t => t.SerialNumberName)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated));
```

**Here is the code where the exception occurs, in my IQueryableExtensions.cs file**

```
public static DataTablesResponse ToDataTablesResponse<TDataModel, TJsonModel>(this IQueryable<TDataModel> data,
    IDataTablesRequest param, IConfigurationProvider cfgProvider)
{
    int totalCount = (data == null) ? 0 : data.Count();
    if (totalCount == 0)
    {
        return new DataTablesResponse(param.Draw, Enumerable.Empty<TJsonModel>(), 0, 0);
    }

    var rows = data.ProjectTo<TJsonModel>(cfgProvider);

    // Apply search
    var searchableColumns = param.Columns
        .Where(c => c.Searchable == true)
        .Select(c => c.Data)
        .ToArray();
    var filteredRows = rows.FilterOnColumns(searchableColumns, param.Search.Value);

    // Apply sorting
    var sortedColumns = param.Columns.GetSortedColumns()
        .ToDictionary(
            sc => sc.Data,
            sc => sc.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant
        );
    var sortedRows = filteredRows.OrderByColumns(sortedColumns);

    // Apply pagination
    var pagedRows = sortedRows
        .Skip(param.Start)
        .Take(param.Length)
        .ToList();

    return new DataTablesResponse(param.Draw, pagedRows, filteredRows.Count(), totalCount);
}
```

The error,

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
>   Parameter name: key

occurs at the `// Apply pagination` section at the bottom. I'm fairly new to this project and have no idea what is causing this error to happen.

After some research, I found a potential solution in adding `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end of the serial numbers line in the Automapper code. However, this caused the new error:

> Missing map from System.Char to System.String. Create using
>   Mapper.CreateMap

because Automapper was trying to map the FirstOrDefault *character* of each string instead of the first in a list of strings. So for now, I have decided to eliminate adding FirstOrDefault as a solution.

Any other ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the following query:

```cs
var pagingModel = new PagingModel();

var data = _context.Parents
    .Select(p => new ParentDto
    {
        ParentProp = p.ParentProp,
        Children = p.Children
            .Select(c => new ChildDto
            {
                ChildProp = c.ChildProp
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .PageAsync(pagingModel);
```

```cs
public class PagingModel
{
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string SortProperty { get; set; }
    public bool Descending { get; set; }
}
```

The `PageAsync` method is from a library I don't have access to the source code. The intention is that it handles the paging, including sorting by a named property, but I don't know the internals of how it does that. Presumably something about its implementation was giving the error, which was the same as you had:

> System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable. (Parameter 'key')

I fixed this by specifying the `SortProperty` for the query:

```cs
var pagingModel = new PagingModel
{
    SortProperty = "ParentProp"
};
```

This presumably explicitly ordered the query by an appropriately. I don't know how it was trying to order it previously.

I suspect something similar must be going on within your `OrderByColumns` method. The upshot is that you need to work out how LINQ is actually being told to order the query, and ensure that it's being ordered by something which makes sense to order by. I know this is a bit vague but I hope it will be helpful to someone getting this error in the future.